# HTML or Javascript or ASP.net: Dynamically Formatting an HTML Table

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic

Today I've encountered a situation in which I have to dynamically format an HTML table.

Specifically what I mean by this, is that I have to add another row after the first 4 data entries are placed.  So, I have to somehow have a counter which keeps track of this, and adds another row after the first 4 columns in the row are placed.

I'm very new to Javascript, but I think that is the right tool to use for this situation (please correct me if I'm wrong, because I can also use jQuery and ASP.net as well).

I've got an ASP.net repeater which is listing the data entries, so adding a bit of javascript before or after this occurs is easy enough.

Has anyone ever done anything like this on a page, and knows how to accomplish this?

```
<table border="0" bordercolor="#FFCC00" style="background-color:#FFFFFF" width="450"     cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3"><tr>
<td><img src="<%# GetFileUrl("MenuItemTeaserImage") %>"></td>
</tr></table>
```

The GetFileUrl is an ASP.net command which is getting me my image.  It is not static and continues to add an additional data entry and corresponding image until all images are exhausted.

Comment: why not use asp.net `table.Rows.Add(row)`. It adds the row at the end of the table. //row is a TableRow

Comment: Mind explaining further?  I'm not sure I understand what you mean, but this could be the ticket.  I really would appreciate it if you can help.  I've got this assignment due soon and I'm stuck on this trivial point. Thanks

Comment: I don't understand how the code shown adds more than one td element, or even more than one img element. The `GetFileUrl()` is inside the `src` of the img element, so how does it continue "to add an additional data entry and corresponding image until all images are exhausted"? Wouldn't you need some sort of looping structure outside the td element?

Comment: The looping structure is actually inherent to the way I've got everything set up... so the td line in the middle gets executed repeatedly, and the table and row lines do not.  My looping structure is an ASP.net repeater, which just has the line in the middle in what it's doing.  The repeater itself is based on the amount of images.

Comment: So what does the repeater actually produce? Do you end up with a table with a single row that has many td elements? If so you can definitely use JS to create additional tr elements and move the td elements around to give four per row. But I'd do the four-per-row processing server-side if I could.

Comment: Yes, you are right about the one single row.  I've decided I will attack this server side, as well.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with you that JavaScript is the right tool to use in this case. It's supported by all browsers and typically extremely fast. It's also leaving many somewhat popular frameworks and supplements looking a bit outdated at this point: as in unnecessary. To add rows with cells and content, get a handle on your table object and use the insertRow(n), insertCell(m) and innerHTML for content. You'll find a complete example [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_table_insertrow.asp).